# The microchip Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am beginner in electronics, I am wonder about microchips that can transmit data between themselves using Bluetooth.

I want to play around with them like the estimate connection, send data, receive and close connection using programming.

I am totally dummy in this area, but I desire to learn it apply my programmers skills.

Could you advise me what to read about such transmitters?

Where to buy them and how to start working?

Comment: A pair of hc05 bluetooth modules and a pair of microcontrollers. Or maybe an esp32s if you dont want to bother with external microcontrollers

Comment: There are lots of options out there. Part of the answer depends on how much you want to get into the details of working with Bluetooth. Are you more interested in transmitting wireless data for the sake of your project, or do you want to learn about Bluetooth?